# How to remove all non-integers from a string? (Python)

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm pretty new to python.  I have a question.  Say for example when I read a line from a file I have a string that looks like this.

```
thestring = '000,5\r\n'
```

How do I remove all non-integers from this string and then convert this string into an integer itself?  Thanks!

Comment: Do you need to be able to read negatives, hex (`0xFFFFFF`), or floats (`-592.45821543e+04`)?

Comment: Just nitpicking, but you do not want to remove _non-integers_, but _non-digits_

Answer (score 11):

Using `str.translate`, this is probably the fastest way to do this:

```
>>> strs = '000,5\r\n'    
>>> from string import ascii_letters, punctuation, whitespace
>>> ignore = ascii_letters + punctuation + whitespace
>>> strs.translate(None, ignore)
'0005'
```

Using `regex`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[^\d]+','',strs)    #or re.sub(r'[^0-9]+','',strs)
'0005'
```

Using `str.join` and `str.isdigit`:

```
>>> "".join([x for x in strs  if x.isdigit()])
'0005'
```

Use **`int()`** to get the integer:

```
>>> int('0005')
5
```

Timing comparisons:

```
>>> strs = strs*10**4
>>> %timeit strs.translate(None, ignore)
1000 loops, best of 3: 441 us per loop

>>> %timeit re.sub(r'[^\d]+','',strs)
10 loops, best of 3: 20.3 ms per loop

>>> %timeit re.sub(r'[^0-9]+','',strs)
100 loops, best of 3: 17.1 ms per loop

>>> %timeit "".join([x for x in strs  if x.isdigit()])
10 loops, best of 3: 19.2 ms per loop
```

Comment: Or translate if you need something slightly faster.

Comment: Great Thanks!  Now suppose my my string is '0005'  How can I reverse my string so that it now reads '5000' ?

Comment: @Binka use this : `'0005'[::-1]`

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the difference in `us` and `ms`?

Comment: @johnthexiii `us` is [microsecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsecond)  ((10^-6)sec) and `ms` is [millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond‎)((10^-3)sec).

Comment: Is this example of translate updated for Python 3.X?